# is there an updatable configuration file for usage in apache tomcat web application?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, configuration

I'm creating a REST API using Jersey and deploying on apache tomcat.
if i put a properties file on the resources folder it is readable but not writeable.
i need a configuration file which can be read from and could be edited without running tomcat all over again. stuff like DB host, port and other stuff.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even wanna do that? Changing property file will end up in performance bottleneck as writting and reading a file involves IO operation. Why not use database to persist and change things?

Comment: it's an option but my customer sees this as more comfortable than altering the DB. + how do you switch a DB if necessary if you don't have a config file to change the ip\port?